# Dynamic DataSource registration for multitenancy app

Tags: java, spring, multi-tenant, liquibase

I'm trying to implement multi-tenancy architecture with database separation in my project. Everything looks fine, but I would like to add new tenants at runtime and  I'm stuck with it. 
I use liquibase in my project and when tenant is added three things must happen at runtime:

1. create new database
2. create new DataSource Bean
3. update database with liquibase

There is no problem to create and to update my newly created database with SpringLiquibase Bean. I'm doing something like this:

```
public void registerTenantBean(String tenantName){
   BeanDefinitionRegistry beanFactory = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
   Properties properties = ... //set my properties
   DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = new DataSourceBuilder(this.getClass().getClassLoader())
            .driverClassName(properties.getDriverClassName())
            .url(properties.getUrl())
            .username(properties.getUsername())
            .password(properties.getPassword());
   DataSource ds = dataSourceBuilder.build();
   BeanDefinition liquibaseDefinition = BeanDefinitionBuilder
            .genericBeanDefinition(TenantLiquibase.class)
            .addConstructorArgReference(ds)
            .setScope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
            .getBeanDefinition();
    beanFactory.registerBeanDefinition(tenantName + "LiquibaseBean", liquibaseDefinition);
}
```

where my TenantLiquibase simply:

```
public class TenantLiquibase extends SpringLiquibase {
  public TenantLiquibase(DataSource dataSource) {
    super.setDataSource(dataSource);
    super.setChangeLog("classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.json");
  }
}
```

And this works fine, but I don't know how to register my datasource `ds` as datasource configuration properties for Spring IoC. Is it possible somehow to do that at this place of code?

Comment: I too have this issue of registering new tenants on-the-fly ! Some input would be of great help